# How to send an access database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I’m having trouble trying to find a way to send a ms access application to someone I have built one for. They say you cannot open it from OneDrive or problems occur. But is the person able to copy it from OneDrive to there desktop? Email works but has a 25 mb limit. How can I simply send an accdb file?

Comment: I see no reason why a file can not be opened from a Onedrive location. I assume that the person has MS Access installed. You must be more specific about the problems that occur.

Comment: I can open an Access .accdb from OneDrive. With OneDrive installed on Windows 11 the Desktop is synchronised so there would be no need to copy a file between the two. I assume your user is remote so you need to sit beside them and see exactly what is happening.

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming that your Access app do not have split database (front-end/back-end). Your Access app users have to download the App to their desktop and launch the App from their desktop.

If for any reason you need to allow your app user to launch and use the Access app from Onedrive. They need to have their own Onedrive account and you need to grant them permissions to run App on top of your Onedrive. Managing of user access on Onedrive can be quite confusing therefore to put it simply download and run the app on desktop.

Whether you are sharing the ACCDE or ACCDB, either way it should work if downloaded and running from the desktop. But if you have forms designed and VBA developed then ACCDE should be shared rather than ACCDB because you won't want the app users to mess around with the VBA/forms.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is just sending the file then you can use OneDrive or Google drive would work fine. You would have to provide them link of the file by using get link or share link option. Even you can use wetransfer that will transfer the file through a link to the email.

As cbk said, you may share accde instead of accdb plus a split database. I alway distribute frontend in the form of .exe file to the end users and backend as a zipped file. You can use SSE Setup maker to make .exe of access file (if your project is free, SSE is free to use, for commercial projects you have to buy a licence). SSE takes care of many things like installing prerequisites (runtime and other), add trusted locations and more. Just my two cents.

Best Regards